# "copy snippet to answer" is not working any more

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I am not able to copy the code of the question and I get this error *(tested with different questions and cleared cache)*:

[image]

This is a test snippet to see if the issue occur on meta or not.

```css
* {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

<sup>Using Chrome  Version 74.0.3729.131 (Build official) (64 bits) | Windows 8.1</sup>

It is *not working* on meta either.

**UPDATE 2**

After manually copying the snippet, I am getting an error while saving (unlike the below error this one it not always happening):

[image]

It seems the whole snippet is not working fine.

Comment: The "copy snippet to answer" button works for me on both Main and Meta in Win10 with Chrome 73.0.3683.103 and Firefox 66.0.3. Do you have an example question on which you are seeing this problem? I just went down the questions on the main page until I found one with a snippet. Do you have any userscripts running?

Comment: We had to roll back a relevant change here due to breakage elsewhere - quite likely you hit it mid-change. Sorry about that - lemme know if you still  see it anywhere?

Comment: @Makyen no userscript installed (almost a fresh install). I face it first here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55941019/8620333 and then I tested other question and still the same issue

Comment: @Shog9 yes it's seems to be fine now.

Comment: @Shog9 will delete the question then, thanks.

Comment: @Makyen issue solved check the comment above [will delete the question]

Comment: hi @Shog9, I am having again the same issue of the copy, something changed again?

Comment: Yep... I see the problem, testing a fix...

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Getting JS Error while clicking Copy Snippet to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328014/289905).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript - and TypeScript - has this nifty little feature where you can test if a variable is "truthy" without worrying about its type. Normally, that's good fun for the whole family, and a great way to eliminate boring ol' `!= null` tests.

...*sometimes*, it means you skip initializing strings that really need to be strings and everything breaks. This is one of those times.

Sorry for the inconvenience!